# Ajax to Rails through jQuery arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, controller

I'm passing an array of arrays from jQuery to Rails through Ajax:

```
search_array = [arr1, arr2];
```

In the console, it shows it to me as this is being passed:

```
search_array => {"0" => ["Trader"], "1" => ["x1"]}
```

Which is correct.

How do I access the values of each array?
I am able to access just arrays of values through normal declaration:

```
myArrayInRails = params[:searchArray]
```

and then do normal calls such as:

```
myVar = myArrayInRails[0]
```

And get the value, but I can't access deeper in with:

```
myVar = myArrayInRails[0][0]
```

It gives me:

```
Undefined method '[]' for nil:nilClass.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a hash so you shouldn't be accessing it through indexes. Doing it through keys will work, p.e.:

```
params[:search_array]['1']
```

Or

```
params[:search_array][:1]
```